# Deleting specific patterns without deleting the whole lines

Tags: vim, vi

Say I want to remove all comment blocks in my source code without deleting the whole lines they are on.
It's possible to achieve this using the

```
:%s/\/\*.*\*\//
```

command. I was wondering, is there a specific delete command for this, or is replacing the matched pattern the best approach? The difference most likely wouldn't be much, I'm just curious.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replacing with nothing really is the idiomatic 'delete this pattern' operation.

```
:%s/pattern//g
```

If you want to blank all lines that contain a pattern, like in your example, the obvious solution is to add wildcard matches around the pattern.

```
:%s/.*pattern.*//
```

An alternative is to use `:global` with a normal mode or Ex command. These two achieve the same thing:

```
:g/pattern/normal! S
:g/pattern/delete|put! _
```

By the way, while I don't recommend using abbreviated command names in scripts or in code that other people might see, I think it's fine to use them interactively. Thus I tend to abbreviate such commands as `:g/pattern/norm! S` and `:g/pattern/d|pu!_`.

Comment: I suspected that this would be the usual way to do things. Nice to the point answer, thanks for your help!